# Strange Neural Network Classification phenomenon

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification, mnist

I'm trying to develop a new weight initialization method but i'm getting a weird training phenomenon. You can see that output node 8 is never the max activation...
[image]

I'm using the matlab patternnet with tansig activation, mse performance, and no bias nodes. I'm trying to classify a subset of the mnist database.

Does anyone have any ideas how to troubleshoot this? Using nguyen-widrow initialization does not see this result, despite having the same architecture.

**edit:**

Inputs: 768xN of values between 0 and 1

Targets: 10xN of values 0 or 1 per respective row. So its like a logic matrix with 1 true per column.

One or more nodes do not activate, i showed the best case.

This occurs with one or more layers (1 to 5), less or more training data (1k to 10k samples.)

Comment: Please, show some data. Also why did you eliminate the bias? - this can affect performance very negatively (depending from data).

Comment: see edit. I eliminated bias as my initialization method does not take into account the bias (for now). Running a control without bias (by changing net.biasConnect to zeros), shows no huge difference vs keeping the bias layers.

Comment: Does the class 8 have some specifics in the data?

Comment: Target 1-10 are digits 0-9 respectively.
The class without activation is not always the 8th node.

Comment: I mean specifics in input data, not targets.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question. The input features are pixel values. A b&w 28 x 28 image is flattened to 784x1. I am trying to classify hand written digits. Each input image is annotated to be the digit 0-9.

Comment: Your current results imply a strict dependency between patterns in class 8 and patterns in all other classes. As you use very common tools, it is most likely a problem in your data, or improper settings. That's all I can tell.

Comment: Did you say the same network works fine with different initialization?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a solution to the problem.

By scaling the weights to be only along the significant domain of the transfer function (-1 to 1), i no longer saw this phenomena.